# Ubuntu one shows pending uploads on iphone after uploading pictures

Tags: ubuntu-one, iphone

Using Ubuntu One Files on iPhone.
After uploading pictures 5 pictures still show pending upload.
These pictures are available on my laptop after syncing.
When I try to open iPhone-Pictures on my iPhone with U1 Files the app crashes.
I've tried deleting all the pictures off my iPhone but it made no difference.

So now I need to fix this 'Pending upload' problem and also need to know how to download the pictures back to my iPhone.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest deleting the app and reinstalling it, this will clear out its data cache which may be corrupted.

For a small number of images, the best way to download the images back to your phone is probably to go to the ubuntu one web site at one.ubuntu.com/photos, and click on the photo you want (to get the highest resolution shown) and then click and hold on the photo, then choose "Save Image".